# Deploy Django with channels and Dephne

Tags: python, django, websocket

i have developed a chatting app using django channels, now i want to deploy it using Dephne and django channels in webfaction server.

i set everything including:

**settings.py**

```
redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        # This example app uses the Redis channel layer implementation asgi_redis
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {"hosts": [(redis_host, 6379)],},
        "ROUTING": "chatbot.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "chatbot.settings")
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

**routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import route, include
from channels import include
channel_routing = [
    # Include sub-routing from an app.
    include("Pchat.routing.websocket_routing", path=r"^/Pchat"),
    # Custom handler for message sending (see Room.send_message).
    # Can't go in the include above as it's not got a `path` attribute to match on.
    include("Pchat.routing.custom_routing"),
]
```

**PP_chat_index.js**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $messages.mCustomScrollbar();
  setTimeout(function() {
      welcomingMessage();
      var ws_path = "/Pchat/webscok/";
      socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host);
      socket.onmessage = function(e) {
                   var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                   chatMessage(data);} }, 100);});
```

but now when i try to connect using ws:// request i got this erorr in the Safari error console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://gadgetron.store/Pchat/webscok/' failed: Unexpected response code: 502
```

and when i try to run Dephne to a specific port number in the terminal:

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 22783 chatbot.asgi:channel_layer
```

i got this erorr in the log:

```
ERROR    Error trying to receive messages: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused
```

Comment: Probably your redis server isn't running correctly at port 6379.